# Document Update Required about the Openstack Autopilot Installation

Tags: maas

I am installing autopilot openstack referring to the guideline on the offical cloud website:
The current issue is that we stucked at the juju bootstrap when excute `sudo openstack-install` at Step 6 "Launch OpenStack Autopilot", please see the attached image:

[image]

The fact is that  the only step we skip is at the step 3 when installing MAAS, as mentioned on the guide [Go to the “Networks” tab and for each of the networks auto-created, click “Edit network” to add the default gateway and DNS server details"], but acutally, we could not find the "Networks" tab, instead, we have "Subnets" tab instead, so we just skip this step.

[image]

Now we could find the installation log `[{"network": ["Node must be configured to use a network"]}]` in `~/.cloud-install/commands.log`.